# How to get the Help window to always open in the same position?

Tags: vim, autocmd

I do this for opening help pages in vertical window:

```
cabbrev help vert botright help
```

this way, it is ok, but a bit disturbing, and it is spamming my `:history` a bit too.
I would like to get Vim to not expand this, just run the command. So when I write `:help topic` I want it to not expanded, but to run the command `:vert botright help topic`
I tried with

```
cabbrev <silent> help vert botright help
```

but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to do at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the perfect solution based on this e-mail:
http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Horizontal-layout-by-default-td1164876.html#a1164886 
So if you want help windows on the right, do this:

```
autocmd FileType help :wincmd H
```

this puts the `'help'` type windows immediately to the right just like `CTRL-W H`. See `:h CTRL-W_H` in vim.
The small problem with it if you have the `hidden` option enabled, just closing the window with `:q` doesn't unload the help window buffer, and if you want to open it again, it will not trigger the FileType event for some reason (why?), so if you use `:set hidden` you need to:

```
autocmd FileType help set bufhidden=unload
```

to get help windows unload, which is the default behavior anyway.

Comment: You have some other option interfering with help buffers distinct from `hidden`: with `vim -u NONE -c 'set hidden' -c 'h abc' -c q` help buffer is unloaded (if it has `buftype=help`, it won't do so if you are editing help file for your own vim script).

Comment: I don't understand what you are triing to say :(
If I do `vim -u NONE -c 'set hidden' -c 'h abc' -c q`, `:ls!` says:

`1 %a "[No Name]" line 1

  2u h-  "map.txt" line 982`

so its there and hidden, and if you want to edit, `:b2` brings it back. So whats your problem ?

Comment: @Walkman I was not aware of 'unlisted' buffers (shown with `:ls!` with a bang) and it was not reachable with `:bnext`.

Comment: I had `hidden` set for help windows, thanks for the `bufhidden` explanation.

Comment: For some weird reason, even using `autocmd FileType help set bufhidden=unload`, if I close the help window, even with the `:helpclose` command, the help buffer will persist as hidden, and the next time I use help,  it won't split the window... but using this it works perfectly for me: `autocmd FileType help set bufhidden=wipe`. This issue has been annoying me for years.

Answer (score 2):

It will only expand *after* you press another key (e.g. <kbd>Space</kbd>)

Perhaps you can make it

```
cabbrev <silent> he vert botright help
```

And then make it a habit to quickly say `:he`<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or indeed

```
:he topic
```

Which will then expand to the full command

#### Edit

If you don't want the expansion at all, I suggest a custom command:

```
:command! Help vert botright help
```

Comment: Sorry, I draw the question dubious. I rewrote it.
So I want Vim not to expand my command just run it.

Comment: I dont accept the answer because you cant make auto-completion with <Tab> :(

Comment: @Kiss: is that a question? Are you angry?

Comment: no. why ? :D Just doesnt work the way it should. I found it:
http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Horizontal-layout-by-default-tp1164876p1164886.html
thanks for help anyway !!

Comment: @Kiss: could you please file your answer as an answer and accept that? It'll help people coming here to find that information

Comment: For help completion you can use `-complete=help` with `-nargs=1`

Answer (score 0):

Although your answer works to see two help topics on the same window (e.g.: `:h bar | h foo`), it is not optimal to see two entries on different windows (e.g.: `h foo | sp | wincmd w | h bar`), as it executes also executes the `wincmd` on the second window thus leaving three vertical windows, even if your monitor can display only two 80 columns windows.

Adding the following lines to `~/.vim/ftplugin/help.vim` executes the `wincmd` only when there is room for another vertical split.

```
" Only do this when not done yet for this buffer
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
   finish
endif

if min(map(range(winnr('$')), 'winwidth(v:val)')) > 160
   wincmd L
endif
```